# .NET Core MVC app not updating View unless entire project is published

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, iis-10

I have a .NET Core MVC app hosted in IIS (development) as well as Azure App Service (production).

When I make a **simple HTML** change to a Razor View and publish just that view, it does not get updated.

It only gets updated if I publish the entire project.

This happens in both IIS and Azure app service.

Is this the default behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the configuration page from Azure App Service:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you publish the complete program to iis, iis compiles and runs it.  .net core mvc disables runtime compilation by default, so even if the view is updated and released, the program that is already running will not compile the new view.

If you want iis to use the new view after the VS update and release the view, you can add a line of code to the startup to enable the function of compiling and running.

1. Add  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation Nuget package to the project.
2. Add following code in startup.cs:

`services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`

3. Publish entire project.
4. After all of these, once you update view and publish. IIS will display new view.

Here is my test result.
[image]

Comment: Here is docs link just in case someone needs more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

***You don't need to do any operations on the portal.***

The article provided by `Lex Li` talks about the content of Razor when compiling. Simply put, C# server code can be written in the `.cshtml file`. After compilation, it will become `projectname.Views.dll`, so when you modify When the `.cshtml` file is not sure which projects it is associated with, it is recommended to update it globally to avoid bugs caused by version issues.

Regarding your current problem of partial update, it is also easy to solve. First, you need to define the file or folder inclusion options when compiling. You need [read offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-3.1#include-files) first.

Below screenshot is my test project.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After my modification and settings, you can publish your customized files or folders to the azure production environment. (**The code setting part is for reference only, coding according to specific projects**)

In the post, you said that you want to publish an html file, then you can right-click the file or folder and select publish file or folder.

[image]

Right click `test` folder.

[image]

From the screenshot message below, we can see that the partial update was successful, the speed is very fast, the modified content is also prompted, and the global update is not performed.

[image]

***prompt:***

1. The above steps are all tested and passed, and the answers and code parts given are for reference only.
2. If you encounter problems during the operation, it is recommended to [raise a support ticket on the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).